# SSRS 2012 - Prompting for credentials

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, credentials, ssrs-2012

I have a 2012 SSRS report with the following requirements:

- When accessed (run), it must prompt for Windows (AD) credentials because users will be launching it from "group workstations" where the current username is "NurseStationNorth" (so I can't use integrated security).
- I'd prefer to hard-code the data-source credentials to ensure that the database connection has all the rights/permissions needed for the report.
- Because the report displays user-specific data, I need to pass the authenticated username (e.g. MyDomain\CoolUser) as a parameter to the report.  I attempted to use the User!UserId global variable but it seemed to reflect the workstation username and not the credentials entered upon running the report.

I understand how to "Manage" the deployed SSRS report via SQL Server Reporting Services "Home" webpage, to configure the Data Source to always prompt for Windows credentials, but I'm not sure this is the behavior I'm seeking.

Any insight is appreciated.
Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Are you able to use Local SQL Users